# How to pass json body to curl command from jenkins pipeline in groovy

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline, http-post

It seems like impossible to pass a string that represents json body for POST request with curl using *sh* command inside Jenkins Pipeline.

I have the following *sh* line inside a pipeline step:

```
def apiCmd = 'curl -X POST --user user:passe --data  \\"{\\"state\\":\\"' + stateStr + '\\",\\"context\\":\\"branch-regression\\"}\\"' + " --url ${Configuration.CommitStatusUpdateURL}
```

now what Jenkins actually runs is:

```
curl -X POST --user user:pass--data '""state":"failure""' '""context":"branch-regression""' --url someurl
```

What is so annoying is that if you want to run the post request with native groovy Jenkins complaints about security stuff.. and if you try with Curl then the JSON isn't parsed well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def curlOut = sh script: """curl -X POST --user user:passe --data '{"state":"${stateStr}", "context": "branch-regression"}' --url ${Configuration.CommitStatusUpdateURL} """, returnOutput: true
```

For the future, you can go to your Jenkins script console (at `your.jenkins.url/script`) and run e.g. this:

```
def stateStr = "OK"
def Configuration_CommitStatusUpdateURL = "https://www.x.com/"
println """curl -X POST --user user:passe --data '{"state":"${stateStr}", "context": "branch-regression"}' --url ${Configuration_CommitStatusUpdateURL} """
```

Result:

```
curl -X POST --user user:passe --data '{"state":"OK", "context": "branch-regression"}' --url https://www.x.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

use three double quote (""") instead of three single quote ''''
for example:

```sh
sh """
curl --request POST --url https://yoururl.com/v1/data --header "Authorization: $TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "client-ref-id: 34567" --data '{\"merchandiseCost\": ${COST},\"merchandiseDescription\": \"${DESCRIPTION}\",\"buyerName\": "${NAME}\",\"buyerPhoneNumber\": \"${PHONE}\",\"storeId\": \"164974727\"}'
"""
```